# map reduce "ORDER BY" 2 columns

Tags: nosql, mapreduce, couchdb

Here is my SQL query, which lists the youngest and most talented dogs:

```
SELECT * FROM dog
ORDER BY dog.age ASC, dog.kudus DESC
```

How can I convert this to a map/reduce?

```
// Map
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.age, doc.kudus], doc);
}
// Reduce
function (keys, values) {
  return ???
}
```

Comment: Don't understand why this question was closed since it has found its answer and people vote for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a map, you are using creating a 1 dimensional index. The problem you are up against   is the sort order you would like your results to show up in for the 'kudus' property are going against the asc order of the age key. Here is a simple fix:

```
// map
function(doc) {
   emit([doc.age, -doc.kudus], doc);
}
```

You do not need a reduce function for this.

It is a bit funny seeing negative numbers, but it gets you the right sort order. You can either Math.abs(key[1]) or use value.kudus to get the real value.

Comment: Excellent! I dealt with (9999999 - doc.kudus), but your negative trick is neat, thx a lot!

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you should not emit `doc` as a value. If you want the document emit `null` as a value and use the `include_docs=true` query parameter.

Comment: Yes, Octavian is right. You are duplicating data in the index if you emit the doc as a value. You could emit the positive doc.kudus if you wanted, but again it's easy enough to calculate from the key, or retrieve if you use the include_docs=true in your query.